# Is the electronic structure of an atom with two or more electrons solvable analytically?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, mathematics, many-body, three-body-problem

I'm thinking about this through the lens of the $n$-body problem in classical mechanics, which was of course proven to be non-analytic for $n\ge3$ by Poincare. Does this same proof extend to a quantum mechanical $n$-body problem, or is there some way to write the hamiltonian that allows us to find an analytic solution for a particular $n>2$?

Comment: You're right, there is no general closed-form solution for the n-body atom Hamiltonian for n > 1 - see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/427663/why-cant-the-schr%C3%B6dinger-equation-be-solved-exactly-for-multi-electron-atoms-d/427752) and links within

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/427663/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Thank you! @NiharKarve